# Botpress Helm Chart

Tags: documentation, botpress

I want to deploy botpress to Kubernetes cluster, one of the most common way or at leat the way that i orefer is using helm chart to deploy(due to a number of reasons including ease of use and manifest maintenance offered by using helm). I have thus far not been lucky to find any resource that offers any guidance if at all botpress has a helm chart.

**What i need**

- Does botpres have a hem chart? if yes, can anyone please share a guide

Any help will be appreciated

**CONTEXT**

- I am planning on using botpres v12, the oss version (community version)

I have reseached via google , even reviewed the githib repo documentation but helm chart seem not to be mentioned anywhere.